# Debugging in WebStorm for node.js

Tags: node.js, debugging, express, ide, webstorm

I recently joined the team which uses the node.js for the development. I am new to the whole node.js ride. I have used IntelliJ based IDEs in the past to configure to run and debug different programming languages. However lack of my understanding of node.js or for some other reason I cannot debug node.js application currently I am working on.

Using node v0.10.48, npm 2.15.1

I can run the application using the WebStorm IDE, but when I run the application, following is what I get in the console tab of debug panel. It also returns a > prompt in the console.

```
/usr/bin/node --debug-brk=44917 --expose_debug_as=v8debug <path_to_startup_js_file?
debugger listening on port 44917
debugger listening on port 44918
```

It stops for the break points that I put in the beginning of the file, but after starting the server nothing happens. Now I can't open client UI application, which makes calls to this node.js/express REST service. Even though it is up and running, I think.

By the way I know how to debug using node-inspector & browser. But not sure what am I doing wrong with IDE. The run profile works fine, but the same profile is not working for debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that application I was working on was spawning child process, which has to be debugged separately as a remote debugger. Webstorm was nice enough to support debugging both master and child thread at the same time, via two separate debugger. 
The current node version used by the project is also relatively old. Which was also the part of the issue with the webstorm. It was verified by the jetbrain support team member.